# indentation problem in my python program

Tags: python, django

I am using the following code and geting some indentation problem

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

I am geting following error

```
File "E:\Softwares\Django-1.1.1.tar\.py", line 7
    def __unicode__(self):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're using a mix of tabs and spaces in your indentation... Use all spaces / all tabs instead. (The most widely adopted style is to use 4 spaces per level of indent.)

To fix this particular instance of the problem, check make the `def __unicode__(self):` line start with the same indent as the `pub_date = ...` line. Use the same indent + four extra spaces for the `return ...` line.

Comment: And a good way to find out is to run the script with `python -tt`.

Answer (score 1):

agree with the others, and you can use editor that can visualize the space to check. e.g.
vim `set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·` (gedit also has such plugins, i think).

Comment: These are some seriously cool listchars! +1 for the idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess here, and the fact that there's a filename* in your traceback speaks against my guess, but hey…

Since your tabs/spaces seem more or less okay (assuming a verbatim copy/paste), is it possible that you pasted the code into the interactive interpreter?

The newline after the field definitions would make the interpreter think that the class definition is done, and thus assume being back at global scope. That would mean that the `def` is indeed falsely indented.

<sub>* `.py` is not exactly a great filename for a python script, btw</sub>